# jQuery ajax never finishes even if POST was successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am trying to get the content of a JSP using AJAX, fill the page with some additional data (the `content` object), and then load the full page I get on a new window:

JavaScript:

```
var request = $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: ctx + "/model/nbReport.jsp",
 dataType: 'html',
 data: {content: content}
});
request.done(function(data) {
 var reportWindow = window.open();
 $(reportWindow.document).html(data);
});
```

This is the JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
     <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @page {
            size: A4 portrait; /* can use also 'landscape' for orientation */
            margin-top: 3.0in;
            margin-bottom: 1.0in;

            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer);
            }

            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
        }

        #page-header {
            display: block;
            position: running(header);
        }

        #page-footer {
            display: block;
            position: running(footer);
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="page-header">

    </div>

    <div id="page-footer">

    </div>
    <div id="page-content">
        ${param.content }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.done()` callback is never executed. I tried also to implement a `.always()` and it is not run as well. Actually if I check the `request` object it has `readyState`=1, that should mean that the post was never completed. But actually checking on the firebug console the POST appears to be successful. 
The response of the post is the HTML contained inside the JSP. No error is reported in the logs.
Does anybody know how could I solve this empasse?
What I aim to do is to get the page "/model/nbReport.jsp", populate it with the data contained in `content` (which is just a list of HTML tags dynamically created) and open the filled page in a new window.

Comment: Did you try a `fail()` and see if there are any errors

Comment: I second adeneo's suggestion. You might have a JavaScript error in your callback that's throwing a wrench into things.

Comment: @adeneo what is strange is that always() is not fired, so i guess neither fail() would be

Comment: Silly question: is your server running?

Comment: Is the Ajax call timing out?

Comment: @adeneo: I tried the  `fail()` as well, but it didn't fire as well. That's why I tried `always()`

Comment: @Wolff: yes, the server is running and the POST returns an OK message with the response as well, that I checked in Firebug. At least as far as I can tell, that's the behaviour in Firefox.